# Set Value for a characteristic fails using BLE ESP32

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, ble

I'm working on a project that uses a Raspberry pi to trigger a microcontroller to read data from an accelerometer for some amount time then have that data available for the RPi to read it over BLE. I Have been able to set up my ESP32 Thing plus as a server and used both a RPi and the BLE scanner app to send it a message a start it to record data. I am struggling to get this data to be set at the characteristic value so that my RPi can then read it.
My aim is to convert that data from an accelerometer that is stored in an array to a string which can then be read by the RPi.
I have tried to just set the value in my code with some string and the actually value I want to send but both of them fail and cause the controller to reboot.
Is it something to do with the way I am setting up the data or is the code structure fundamentally wrong? please see code below.

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SERVICE1_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC1_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

#define CHARACTERISTIC2_UUID "279766d1-630f-4db9-9b84-81731a59d46b"

#define CHARACTERISTIC3_UUID "837c3fbd-77e6-43ad-9921-c3526139a7dc"

BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic1;
BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic2;
BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic3;

//Accelerometer Variable
const int xpin = A2;                  // x-axis of the accelerometer
const int ypin = A4;                  // y-axis
const int zpin = A3;                  // z-axis (only on 3-axis models)
int LoopCounter = 0;
const int ArraySize = 250;
int XValueArray[ArraySize];
int YValueArray[ArraySize];
int ZValueArray[ArraySize];
int AValueArray[ArraySize];
char XValueString[500] = "";
char YValueString[500] = "";
char ZValueString[500] = "";
bool MeasurmentTaking = false;
bool ValidMessage = false;
int XValue = 0;
int YValue = 0;
int ZValue = 0;
//Millis variables 
unsigned long PreviousMillis = 0;
unsigned long CurrentMillis = 0;
const int PeriodRead = 4;
const int NumberOfPoints = 250;

//Class to read incomming messages 
class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
  
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic1) {
      std::string RecievedValue = pCharacteristic1->getValue();
      
      
      if (RecievedValue == "Start") {
        MeasurmentTaking = true;
        ValidMessage = true;
      }//If
      else{
        }//Else
    }
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //Set up accelerometer pins 
  pinMode(xpin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ypin, INPUT);
  pinMode(zpin, INPUT);

  //Set up BLe device 
  BLEDevice::init("MyESP32");
  
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE1_UUID);               //XAxis accellerometer
  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic1 = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC1_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY 
                                       );

  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic2 = pService->createCharacteristic(       //YAxis accellerometer
                                         CHARACTERISTIC2_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY 
                                       );

  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic3 = pService->createCharacteristic(       //ZAxis accellerometer  
                                         CHARACTERISTIC3_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY 
                                       );
                                       

  
  pCharacteristic1->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());

  pCharacteristic1->setValue("X");
  pCharacteristic2->setValue("Y");
  pCharacteristic3->setValue("Z");
  pService->start();


  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE1_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);  // functions that help with iPhone connections issue
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(MeasurmentTaking);
  Serial.println(ValidMessage);
  
  //Record Data from accelerometer to array 
  if (ValidMessage == true){
    MeasurmentTaking = true;
    while (MeasurmentTaking == true){
          CurrentMillis = millis();
          if (LoopCounter == NumberOfPoints){
            MeasurmentTaking = false;
            LoopCounter = 0;
            }//If
          else if(CurrentMillis - PreviousMillis >= PeriodRead){
            int XValue = analogRead(xpin);
            Serial.println(XValue);
            XValueArray[LoopCounter] = XValue;
            
            int YValue = analogRead(ypin);
            Serial.println(YValue);
            YValueArray[LoopCounter] = YValue;
            
            int ZValue = analogRead(zpin);
            Serial.println(ZValue);
            ZValueArray[LoopCounter] = ZValue;

            AValueArray[LoopCounter] = ZValue;
            PreviousMillis = CurrentMillis;
            LoopCounter = LoopCounter + 1;
            }//Else If
            
          }//While

    //Convert array values to string
    Serial.print("XValueArray");
    for (int i = 0; i <= ArraySize; i++){
      Serial.println(XValueArray[i]);
      int buff1 = XValueArray[i];
      char str1 [7];
      sprintf(str1,"%u" ,buff1); 
      strcat(XValueString,str1);
      strcat(XValueString, ",");
      }//For
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("YValueArray");
    for (int j = 0; j <= ArraySize; j++){
      Serial.println(YValueArray[j]);
      int buff2 = YValueArray[j];
      char str2 [7];
      sprintf(str2,"%u" ,buff2); 
      strcat(YValueString,str2);
      strcat(YValueString, ",");
      }//For
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("ZValueArray");
    for (int k = 0; k <= ArraySize; k++){
      Serial.println(ZValueArray[k]);
      int buff3 = ZValueArray[k];
      char str3 [7];
      sprintf(str3,"%u" ,buff3); 
      strcat(ZValueString,str3);
      strcat(ZValueString, ",");
        }//For
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("XvalueString");
    Serial.println(XValueString);
    Serial.print("YvalueString");
    Serial.println(YValueString);
    Serial.print("ZvalueString");
    Serial.println(ZValueString);
    MeasurmentTaking = false;

    //Set values as new data 
    pCharacteristic1->setValue("Test X");
    pCharacteristic2->setValue("Test Y");
    pCharacteristic3->setValue("Test Z");
    ValidMessage = false;
  }
  else{
    }
  
  
  delay(1000);
}
```

Example of the string I would like to send.

```
<1967,1967,1989,2000,2000,2000,2003,1997,1984,1980,1999,1999,2000,2000,2021,2000,1969,1973,1999,2000,1999,1995,1995,1986,1978,1998,1991,2000,2002,1999,2000,1968,1989,1995,2000,2000,2000,2001,1983,1979,1993,2000,1997,2002,2000,1999,1967,1986,1988,1999,2000,2001,2000,1983,1971,2059,1999,2000,2000,1997,2000,1963,1989,1997,2000,1999,2015,2003,1984,1979,1986,2003,2000,1997,2001,2001,1968,1984,1991,1998,1997,1998,2000,1981,1979,2000,2000,2002,2002,1999,2000,1968,2016,1997,2000,2000,2000,2001,1981,1982,1991,2000,2000,2001,2000,2000,1967,1987,1998,2005,2001,2000,2001,1984,1980,2000,2000,2000,2000,2001,1998,1967,1994,2000,2000,2000,2000,1997,1985,1981,1996,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,1971,1989,1999,2001,2001,2000,2000,1984,1970,1999,2001,2000,2000,1999,2000,1968,1987,2000,1990,2000,2001,1997,1985,1980,1995,2000,2000,1999,2000,2000,1968,1989,1997,2000,2000,2002,2006,1984,1979,1994,1998,1998,2000,2000,2000,1968,1990,1997,2000,1999,1998,2000,1983,1980,1998,2000,1997,1999,1998,2002,1963,1985,2000,2000,1999,2002,1999,1983,1971,1995,1989,1985,2000,1999,2000,1966,1989,2001,2000,2000,1983,2000,1982,1978,1997,2000,2000,2001,2003,1999,1967,1989,1997,1999,2000,2002,1999,1997,1979,1997,1999,1999,1999,1999,2000,1968,1990,1999,1999,2002,2000,2000,1983,1978,1859>
```

Thank you for any help or guidance to an answer.